# How does one extract URLs from a string? (Any language)

Tags: string, url, language-agnostic

I realise this question has been asked many times across Stack Overflow and across the web, in fact, I have about 20 tabs open just now with apparent solutions to this problem.

The thing is *every single answer* says something along the lines of

> You *could* use Regex, but it's not a good idea and doesn't reliably work, but I won't offer any alternatives.

So my question is this - Is there really *no* reliable, definitive way we can extract URLs from text?

Comment: No other elegant solution than regex.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regular Expressions are extremely powerful tools.  Like most powerful tools, they are seriously misunderstood, dangerous in the hands of many of their users, and the best answer to certain tasks.**  Matching known patterns in strings is what they exist for.  Once you have a good URL pattern in hand it will work all the time in the context it was designed for.  The reason everyone shies away from using them is that creating a good URL pattern for a specific context is difficult work.  The pattern will vary by the execution environment (*e.g.*, operating system for `file:` URLs), by the programming language and/or library in use, *etc.*

For the specific case of HTTP URLs, there is a [clear definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) that is mostly adhered to, and you can build a reliable regular expression from it with almost any language or library.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there really no reliable, definitive way we can extract URLs from text?

Well, anything which is in string formatted list needs a careful exception handling. That is said, once you have that handling in place it should be working fine.

The [regexp  with a uri schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) may do the trick may look something similar to:

```
<a href="(?<url>http://.*?)".*>(?<text>.+?)<\/a>
```

That's a **.NET regexp though**, so you may need to modify it to work on your platform language.

Comment: that'll work for tagged links in html, OP asks for any string.

Comment: I just added the rest of answer. I think the parsing process just needs a good exception handling in first place.

Comment: Look at what you quoted: He wants to extract URLs from **text**, this could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract URL from any string there is no other choice than using Regex.
In fact URI Scheme is defined (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) and if you go through all it's aspects, regex is very reliable.